# How to delete or modify an element from a retrieved JSON API call?

Tags: python, json, rest

As a Python newbie, I seem to struggle with a use case that I need to implement. The use case is that I need to retrieve some data using a REST call and later on send that data (modified) to another REST API but then with some fields manipulated, for example, **rename a property or delete a property**.

```
# get the data
service1 = requests.get(http://myrestservice_1.com)

# modify the data?
# delete or rename a property?

# send the data
service2 = request.post(url=http://myrestservice_2.com, json=service1.json())
```

Example of the data that I retrieve using a Rest call:

```
{
  "prop1" : "value1",
  "prop2" : "value2"
{
```

How can I, for example, delete or rename the `prop2` value from the JSON when it needs to be forwarded the data to another service?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Once you have load it (with `json.load` or `json.loads`) you will have plain Python structures like lists or dictionaries, and you can manipulate them without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

`requests.get()` returns a `Response` object, which among other things contains the payload you want to decode. You can either do that yourself:

```
data = json.loads(service1.text)
```

or let `requests` do it for you.

```
data = service1.json()
```

Once you have modified `data` as necessary, you need to re-encode the data structure. Again, you can do so manually

```
service2 = request.post(url=http://myrestservice_2.com, data=json.dumps(data))
```

or let `requests` do it for you.

```
service2 = request.post(url=http://myrestservice_2.com, json=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response = requests.get()
```

gets you a Response object.
From there,

```
response.text
```

gets you a string with the response of the REST api.

```
response.status_code
```

gets you the HTTP status code of the call you just did.

And,

```
response.json()
```

gets you a Python dict that you can interact with.